# How to use filter with Serilog.Sinks.EventLog

Tags: serilog, serilog-aspnetcore, serilog-expressions

I'm really not sure what I'm missing. Filtering is not working at all for Serilog.Sinks.EventLog. Everything gets logged no matter what I've tried in the Filter configuration. I've used old syntax, new sytanx, different properties, etc. for the expression.

Does EventLog support filters and if so, how do I fix this?

Here's an excerpt from my appsettings.json file.

```
...
        {
                "Name": "EventLog",
                "Filter": [
                    {
                        "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
                        "Args": {
                            "expression": "Contains(@Message, 'EventLog:')"
                        }
                    }
                ],

                "Args": {
                    "source": "WebUI Application",
                    "logName": "Application",
                    "manageEventSource": true,
                    "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Verbose",
                    "levelSwitch": "$controlSwitch"
                }
        }
...
```

Configuration:

- .Net 8
- Serilog.AspNetCore v8.0.0
- SerilogExpressions v4.0.0
- Serilog.Sinks.EventLog v3.1.0

I've tried various configurations for the expression, old syntax, new syntax, etc. to no avail.

Comment: config processing is handled by Serilog.Settings.Configuration;
Filtering is handled by Serilog;
EventLog just emits stuff that arrives at its doorl
Hence the chances are that the config parsing is not processing your `"Filter"` (correctly, or at all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding below code into `program.cs` works and only creates event logs for log level 'Error'. I have below example from a sample console app with .Net8. [Here](https://github.com/chinmay-trivedi/SeriLogExamples) is the github repo [link](https://github.com/chinmay-trivedi/SeriLogExamples) with this example and some other examples on Serilog usage in different type of .Net projects.

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()            
            .WriteTo.Logger( lev => lev
            .Filter.ByIncludingOnly( l => l.Level == LogEventLevel.Error)
            .WriteTo.EventLog("SerilogConsoleApp.Eample", manageEventSource:true))
.CreateLogger();
```

[image]

I noticed that you have wrong config structure, Try changing your `appsettings.json` with below config and see.

```
{
  "Name": "EventLog",
  "Args": {
    "source": "SerilogConsoleApp.Eample",
    "logName": "SerilogConsoleApp",
    "manageEventSource": true,
    "filter": [
      {
        "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
        "Args": {
          "expression": "Level = 'Error'"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```